# How wrap a picture (currently in background) with text

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a picture that I set as background image, and I want to disallow tha fact that the text override the picture.
In addition to that, below the picture, the text has to take the full-width, and the whole text is in the same paragraph!

The website is for mobile devices, so I think that flex box is not the right choice for all devices!

The picture size is 64*64 and it can't be other size!

http://jsfiddle.net/RF8b7/ or this is my current code

```
<div id="mydiv" class="myclass">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </div>

#mydiv{
background: transparent url(../contents/Picture.png) no-repeat 10px 0;
background-size: 64px 64px;}
```

How can I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to make a non-visible copy of the picture appear over the same location as the background copy, and wrap the text around that?  E.g., use `visibility: hidden;` on the image copy...

Comment: Could you put the image separately from the text (in a different container)?

Comment: @abiessu : thanks! I will try it now but it isn't very clean, it looks dirty for me, is it?

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 : It is possible, yes!

Comment: Here is my version of the Fiddle, hopefully it works well for you! http://jsfiddle.net/RF8b7/5/

Comment: @clement Please look at my answer. Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/aBoniKe/1/edit

Comment: If the requirements include that the image be placed specifically in the background, then there isn't much else you can do to tell the text where to go...

Comment: @abiessu You could place a transparent image over the background image which would structure the text around the image in background, but that would require putting in an image which makes this method pretty stupid. But then again it allows for use of a background image and text structure.

Comment: @ChrisFrank: I didn't say it was a good idea, just trying to think of ways to match the seeming requirement that the visible image be in the background...

Comment: @abiessu Yeah I was just trying to give a solution to using a background image while keeping a text structure. The method I said in my opinion is stupid, and requires more work than necessary but if lets say this is a homework assignment, and the instructor requires you to place the image in the background of the div while structuring text around it, my solution would meet requirements (I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way I can think of :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RF8b7/4/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="myclass">
    <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01854/readers-moon-1_1854200j.jpg"/>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        </div>
```

CSS :

```
img{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: finaly, I use a div and I set a background-image to this div, in addition to the float left indeed! Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

You can add another image to the document with an `img` tag, `visibility: hidden`, and `float:left`, and it will work the same. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/OJAjivEc/1/edit)

## Option 2

If you place the image separately from the text, then you can use `float: left;` and the text will go around it. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/aBoniKe/1/edit)

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01854/readers-moon-1_1854200j.jpg">
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
  float: left;
}
```

**Explanation**
Setting an image as the background image for a `div` containing text is normally a bad idea (unless you want it as a background). Separating the image and the div into separate containers allows you to have more control over the positioning.

Comment: It's deja-vu all over again!

Comment: @abiessu We came up with the same idea at the same time.

Comment: @abiessu [but they don't](http://www.forbes.com/sites/timmaurer/2012/06/28/great-minds-dont-think-alike-the-business-of-financial-planning/)

Comment: For option 1, why do you use `float: left;`?  Is the background image guaranteed to be in that spot?

Comment: @abiessu You're right that using `float` can get sloppy, but in this case, I believe it works. I would have to know where in a webpage that this is going to be sure, though.